# How to set mySQL data source for combo box (C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

I am a beginner at C# and am having some serious issues setting the data source of a combo box. What I want to have happen is as follows: I want the combo box on my C# windows forum to be populated with the string names in just one column of a table in my mySQL database.

The mySQL table has the following format:

```
river_id, river_name, ....... (other columns) 
_____________________________________________
1           river1
2           river2         
3           river3
4           river4
5           river5
6           river6
```

What I want to happen is have the combo box be populated with each river name.
Here is my attempt:

```
 string query = "SELECT * FROM sources";
       MySqlDataAdapter riverSourcesAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query,connectionString);
       DataSet riverDataSet = new DataSet();
       riverSourcesAdapter.Fill(riverDataSet);

       comboBox1.Text = riverDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

I also tried setting the combo box datasource and datamember in the designer instead, but that approach did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = riverDataSet.Tables[0];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "<column name>";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "<column name>";
```

Comment: Well that was simple..... It works perfectly, thank you!  Could you explain the need for the '<>' symbols please?

Comment: this is just placeholder for real column name :)

Answer (score 0):

your code should be like this..

```
comboBox1.DataSource = riverDataSet;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "river_name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "river_id";
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```